# EC2 instance not running User Data script in Advanced Settings -> User Data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I cannot get my newly launched ec2 instances to run the User Data script specified in Advanced Settings -> User Data.

If I manually SSH into my instance after it is done initializing and type "cd DIRECTORY", & "npm run SCRIPT" the instance will run the NodeJS app perfectly. However I cannot get the User Data script to do this automatically on ec2 instance initialization.

I saw in similar articles to include "#!/bin/bash" at the beginning of my script but this has not made a difference.

**When launching a new instance, in Advanced Settings -> User Data script I have:**

```
#!/bin/bash <- tried with and without this
cd DIRECTORY
npm run SCRIPT
```

Which is the exact command I use to run my NodeJS app by manually SSH-ing into the instance. Is there something I am missing??

I am launching an Amazon Linux T3.micro instance from my AMI.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot or fix this??

Comment: You definitely have to have `#!/bin/bash` as the very first line. You can read the documentation here: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html My guess is that it is running as a user that doesn't have `npm` in the path, or maybe `npm` isn't installed yet at the time this runs. You need to check the logs on the server to see if the cloud-init process logged any errors.

Comment: Check the contents of the log file at `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`. See also: [Log your EC2 Linux user data and then ship it to the console logs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-log-user-data/)